# Images from Flickr not seen in Android app

Tags: android, image, load, slideshow, flickr

I am loading a Flickr URL to a webView to load in the following way

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.flickrWebView);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl(flickrURL);
```

The page gets loaded smoothly without any problem. But when I click on image/picture from Flickr page to zoom and start slideshow, the images/pictures are not loaded and only a black screen is loaded. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the following setting to webview.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    WebViewClient webclient = new WebViewClient();
    webview.setWebViewClient(webclient);
    webview.loadUrl(flickrURL);
```